# Low processor efficiency with almost same CUDA kernels

Tags: performance, cuda, gpgpu, nvprof

I have created three synthetic CUDA kernels, which are almost all doing only arithmetic operations. All three kernels are the same, except each of them does a different number of operations. Kernel #1 does 8 operations, Kernel #2 does 16 operations and Kernel #3 does 32. Here are the implementations of CUDA kernel for all three.

Kernel #1:

```
#ifndef kernelWGSXMAPIXLLXOPS8_H_
#define kernelWGSXMAPIXLLXOPS8_H_

__global__ void WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS8 (const float *GIn, float *GOut, const float M, const float N, const float P) {

        int gid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

        float MF = (float) M;
  float NF = (float) N;
  float PF = (float) P;

  for (int lcdd = 0; lcdd < 1; lcdd++) {
    float temp1 = 1.0;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    ... // 8 FMA operations
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;

    GOut[gid] = temp1;
  }

}

void WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS8_wrapper (const float *GIn, float *GOut,
                               const float M, const float N, const float P,
                               int numBlocks, int threadPerBlock) {
        WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS8<<<numBlocks, threadPerBlock>>> (GIn, GOut, M, N, P); 
}


#endif
```

Kernel #2:

```
#ifndef kernelWGSXMAPIXLLXOPS16_H_
#define kernelWGSXMAPIXLLXOPS16_H_

__global__ void WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS16 (const float *GIn, float *GOut, const float M, const float N, const float P) {

        int gid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

        float MF = (float) M;
  float NF = (float) N;
  float PF = (float) P;

  for (int lcdd = 0; lcdd < 1; lcdd++) {
    float temp1 = 1.0;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    ... // 16 FMA operations
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;

    GOut[gid] = temp1;
  }

}

void WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS16_wrapper (const float *GIn, float *GOut,
                               const float M, const float N, const float P,
                               int numBlocks, int threadPerBlock) {
        WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS16<<<numBlocks, threadPerBlock>>> (GIn, GOut, M, N, P); 
}

#endif
```

Kernel #3:

```
#ifndef kernelWGSXMAPIXLLXOPS32_H_
#define kernelWGSXMAPIXLLXOPS32_H_

__global__ void WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS32 (const float *GIn, float *GOut, const float M, const float N, const float P) {

        int gid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

        float MF = (float) M;
  float NF = (float) N;
  float PF = (float) P;

  for (int lcdd = 0; lcdd < 1; lcdd++) {
    float temp1 = 1.0;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    ... // 32 FMA operations
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;

    GOut[gid] = temp1;
  }

}

void WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS32_wrapper (const float *GIn, float *GOut,
                               const float M, const float N, const float P,
                               int numBlocks, int threadPerBlock) {
        WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS32<<<numBlocks, threadPerBlock>>> (GIn, GOut, M, N, P); 
}

#endif
```

The total number of threads have been set to 16384, and block size is 256. I have calculated the total GFlops of each of these kernels and are equal to 20.44, 56.53, and 110.12 GFlops. I was trying to come up with an explanation, but nothing comes to my mind. So I tried using nvprof and monitored all metrics. All metrics are almost equal, Here are some of the metrics that look important to me (I also included results for kernel 1 to 3):

```
sm_efficiency_instance:   14.99, 16.78, 19.82 %
ipc_instance:             0.57 , 0.93 , 1.53   
inst_replay_overhead:     0.399, 0.268, 0.165
dram_write_throughput:    18.08, 17.72, 16.9 GB/s
issued_ipc:               0.99 , 1.18 , 1.52
issue_slot_utilization:   19.48, 24.64, 33.76 %
stall_exec_dependency:    21.84, 26.38, 42.95 %
```

As it's clear, both of them have the same dram_write_throughput, since all are writing same amount of data to the DRAM, and the total number of threads is the same. What I don't understand is sm_efficiency. My kernels are all doing arithmetics (the same), how come their sm_efficiency is not the same. Also, why having more arithmetic in the same kernel increases the efficiency? My understanding is, all of them should have the same problem for finding warps to locate on SM.

Can anyone help me to understand the difference of GFlops, using below metrics?

Comment: The generate PTX is showing exactly what I expect to see. For Gflops, I count how many operations in total is being done, divided by the total running time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that you have not "saturated" the GPU with work.  There are various overheads associated with the kernel launch.  If the amount of time the kernel spends computing is small compared to this overhead, then your calculation will be skewed by the overhead.

T = Overhead time(OT) + Calculation time(CT)

Flops/s = Flops/T  = Flops/(OT + CT)

If the calculation time is small compared to the Overhead time (which is the case for your kernels) then your calculation will be affected by the overhead time.  On the other hand, if Calculation time is large enough compared to the overhead, then the overhead has relatively little effect on the results.

Here's a full test case, with a few cases run, CUDA 9.1, Tesla P100 PCIE:

```
$ cat t79.cu
#ifndef SLEN
#define SLEN (8)
#endif
#ifndef NTPB
#define NTPB (256)
#endif
#ifndef BLKS
#define BLKS (16384/NTPB)
#endif
const size_t blks = BLKS;
const size_t ntpb = NTPB;
typedef float Ftype;
#include <iostream>
template <int LEN>
__global__ void WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS (Ftype *GOut, const Ftype M) {

        int gid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

        Ftype MF = (Ftype) M;

  for (int lcdd = 0; lcdd < 1; lcdd++) {
    float temp1 = 1.0;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
    if (LEN > 8){
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;}
    if (LEN > 16){
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;}
    if (LEN > 32){
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;}
    if (LEN > 64){
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;}
    if (LEN > 128){
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;}
    if (LEN > 256){
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;
      temp1 = temp1 * MF + temp1;}


#ifdef NO_WRITE
      if (temp1 == -10.0)
#endif
        GOut[gid] = temp1;
  }

}


int main(){

  float et;
  Ftype *GOut;
  const Ftype M = 1.0;
  cudaMalloc(&GOut, blks*ntpb*sizeof(Ftype));
  cudaEvent_t start, stop;
  cudaEventCreate(&start); cudaEventCreate(&stop);
  WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS<SLEN><<<blks, ntpb>>> (GOut, M);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaEventRecord(start);
  WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS<SLEN><<<blks, ntpb>>> (GOut, M);
  cudaEventRecord(stop);
  cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
  cudaEventElapsedTime(&et, start, stop);
  unsigned long long flpcnt = SLEN*2*blks*ntpb;
  float Kflops_s = flpcnt/et;
  std::cout << "MFlops per sec: " << Kflops_s/1000 << " kernel time: " << et << "ms" << std::endl;
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_60 -o t79 t79.cu
$ ./t79
MFlops per sec: 14371.9 kernel time: 0.01824ms
$ nvprof ./t79
==14676== NVPROF is profiling process 14676, command: ./t79
MFlops per sec: 10101.1 kernel time: 0.025952ms
==14676== Profiling application: ./t79
==14676== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:  100.00%  3.2320us         2  1.6160us  1.2480us  1.9840us  void WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS<int=8>(float*, float)
      API calls:   98.31%  389.62ms         1  389.62ms  389.62ms  389.62ms  cudaMalloc
                    1.10%  4.3574ms       376  11.588us     357ns  465.31us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.42%  1.6829ms         4  420.73us  272.19us  642.45us  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.12%  487.27us         4  121.82us  90.094us  164.09us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.02%  80.363us         2  40.181us  15.789us  64.574us  cudaLaunch
                    0.00%  17.118us         2  8.5590us  8.1400us  8.9780us  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                    0.00%  13.118us         2  6.5590us  5.4290us  7.6890us  cudaEventRecord
                    0.00%  10.603us         2  5.3010us  1.2440us  9.3590us  cudaEventCreate
                    0.00%  8.5080us         8  1.0630us     460ns  1.7500us  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%  8.4590us         1  8.4590us  8.4590us  8.4590us  cudaEventElapsedTime
                    0.00%  7.1350us         1  7.1350us  7.1350us  7.1350us  cudaEventSynchronize
                    0.00%  6.8430us         4  1.7100us     180ns  5.9720us  cudaSetupArgument
                    0.00%  4.7800us         3  1.5930us     437ns  2.8480us  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  2.3490us         2  1.1740us     361ns  1.9880us  cudaConfigureCall
$ nvcc -arch=sm_60 -o t79 t79.cu -DSLEN=512 -DBLKS=32768 -DNTPB=1024
$ ./t79
MFlops per sec: 8.08072e+06 kernel time: 4.25206ms
$
$ nvprof --metrics  sm_efficiency_instance,ipc_instance,issued_ipc,issue_slot_utilization,stall_exec_dependency    ./t79
==15447== NVPROF is profiling process 15447, command: ./t79
==15447== Some kernel(s) will be replayed on device 0 in order to collect all events/metrics.
Replaying kernel "void WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS<int=512>(float*, float)" (done)
Replaying kernel "void WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS<int=512>(float*, float)" (done)
MFlops per sec: 193432 kernel time: 177.632ms
==15447== Profiling application: ./t79
==15447== Profiling result:
==15447== Metric result:
Invocations                               Metric Name                           Metric Description         Min         Max         Avg
Device "Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (0)"
    Kernel: void WGSXMAPIXLLXOPS<int=512>(float*, float)
          2                                issued_ipc                                   Issued IPC    1.972106    1.972388    1.972247
          2                    issue_slot_utilization                       Issue Slot Utilization      98.23%      98.24%      98.24%
          2                     stall_exec_dependency   Issue Stall Reasons (Execution Dependency)      16.35%      16.36%      16.36%
          2                                       ipc                                 Executed IPC    1.971976    1.972254    1.972115
          2                             sm_efficiency                      Multiprocessor Activity      99.78%      99.78%      99.78%
$
```

The first run, with numbers that match yours (16384 threads, 256 threads per block, 8 FFMA instructions) shows a kernel duration of ~17us.  However when we run that case in the profiler, we observe that the actual kernel execution is only about 1.5us, and the remainder is various kinds of overhead, including kernel launch latency, as well as the latency of using the `cudaEvent` system for timing.  So this throws the numbers way off.

On the other hand, when we launch a large amount of blocks, and threads per block, and work per thread, we get a number that is 80% of the peak capability of the P100.

Most of your metrics are increasing (getting better) as you go from kernel 1 to 3 (excepting dram throughput, which is sensible.  As the kernel time increases, for the same amount of data written, the dram average throughput goes down).  This is consistent with giving the GPU more work, so that it can hide various kinds of latency and amortize overhead over a large quantity of work.

Let's take a look at some of these metrics for the final run/"large" kernel above:

```
2                 issued_ipc                                   Issued IPC    1.972106    1.972388    1.972247
2     issue_slot_utilization                       Issue Slot Utilization      98.23%      98.24%      98.24%
2      stall_exec_dependency   Issue Stall Reasons (Execution Dependency)      16.35%      16.36%      16.36%
2                        ipc                                 Executed IPC    1.971976    1.972254    1.972115
2              sm_efficiency                      Multiprocessor Activity      99.78%      99.78%      99.78%
```

IPC is at around 2 per clock, higher than your kernel 3.   Note that an IPC of 2 is a reasonable upper bound here: `sm_60` SM has 64 single-precision units, enough to schedule 2 FFMA instructions per clock.

The SM efficiency and issue_slot_utilization are similar metrics.  This means that that about 98% of the time, the SM could issue one or more instructions in any given clock cycle.

The stall(exec dependency) is answering the question, "across all the actual stall situations, what percent were due to execution dependency?".  Your kernel has an execution dependency between each line of source code - since each depends on the results of the previous line.  This means at the assembly level, each FFMA instruction will depend on the results of the previous one, so it cannot be issued until the previous one is complete.

If the SM were undersubscribed with available work, then the stall exec dependency would go up, because the thing preventing issuance of additional work would be the exec dependency.  A number of 16% here means that about 5/6 of the time, when there is a stall scenario, it is not due to an exec dependency.  In other words, even though we have plenty of execution dependency in this kernel, most of the time when there was a stall, it was not because the GPU would have liked to go to the next line of code to issue - it was for some other reason.

Summary:

There seem to be at least 2 issues, both related to different kinds of latency:

1. At the very small kernel sizes (e.g. 16384 total threads) the kernel execution time is short, so measurement is clouded by e.g. kernel launch latency and possibly measurement latency.
2. The kernel sizes, being very small, do not saturate the GPU with as much parallel work as can be delivered, and so things like IPC and `sm_efficiency` are lower than they need to be, and stall reasons: exec dependency is relatively high.

Any time you see a `sm_efficiency` that is that low, a possible conclusion is that not enough parallel work has been exposed to the GPU, and so neither compute throughput nor memory are the limiting factors, but instead latency is the limiting factor to performance.

This is consistent with [the analysis-driven optimization logic](http://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC-2010/pdfs/2012_GTC2010.pdf) (slide 46 and beyond)

and can be rectified by exposing more work to the GPU.

Comment: This is a great answer to my issue. Thanks much Robert!